# Java| Getting wrong return from function

Tags: java

I have this function :

```
public static String checkPeace(int y, int x, player p) 
{
    if(p instanceof black)
    {
        black b = (black)p;
        for(int i=0 ; i < b.blackPeaces.length ; i++)
        {
            if(b.blackPeaces[i] == null)
                break;  
                if(b.blackPeaces[i].getXaxis() == x && b.blackPeaces[i].getYaxis() == y )
                {

                    return b.blackPeaces[i].Print(b);
                }
    }
        //TODO add else for white 
    }
    return "\u0020";
```

and im getting the wrong output from `b.blackPeaces[i].getXaxis()`and`b.blackPeaces[i].getXaxis()`

b.blackPeaces is an obj array thet is build from the following code:

```
peace[] blackPeaces = new peace[21];

public void Build()
{
    for(int i=0 , j =0; i < 16 ; i++)
    {
        if(i%2!=0)
        {
            this.blackPeaces[j] = new pawn("BlackPawn"+i,13,i);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

the `getXaxis()` function is a simple function from the pawn class:

```
public int getXaxis() {
    return X;
}
```

for some reason the `b.blackPeaces[i].getXaxis()`and`b.blackPeaces[i].getXaxis()`functions always returns 0

another weird thing that I have 2 of each pawn field(X,Y,Name) in the varible window(Debug)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BymCfY6aWlMPYlBReklLQUFidVk&authuser=0

what could be the reason ?

EDIT1:
here is the definition : Pawn:

```
'package ChessGame;

public class pawn extends piece {
    String Name;
    int Y;
    int X;

    public pawn(String Name, int Y, int X)
    {
        super(Name, Y, X);
    }

    @Override
    public void Move(int NewY, int NewX) 
    {
        Y = NewY;
        X = NewX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getYaxis() {
        return Y;
    }

    @Override
    public int getXaxis() {
        return X;
    }

    @Override
    public String Print(player p) {

        if(p instanceof black)
            return "\u265f";
        else
            return "\u2659";

    }

}
' piece : 'package ChessGame;

abstract public class piece
{
    int Y ;
    int X;
    String Name;

    public piece(String Name, int Y, int X)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
    public String Print(player p)
    {
        if(p instanceof black)
            return "";
        else
            return "";

    }


    public void Move(int NewY, int NewX) 
    {
        Y = NewY;
        X = NewX;

    }

    public int getYaxis()
    {
        return Y;
    }
    public int getXaxis()
    {
        return X;
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Show the definitions of `paawn` and `peace`. (Also, by the way, it's spelled "piece")

Comment: @immibis (:\ thx will correct the spelling) I added the definition to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece constructor initializes teh fields X and Y define in piece. But the subclass pawn's getters return the values of the fields X and Y defined in pawn, and which are never initialized.

You shouldn't have those fields in the subclass. They're already in the superclass.

Also, your code is unreadable to any Java developer because you don't respect any naming conventions. Variables should start with a lowercase letter: `x`, `y`. Classes should start with an uppercase letter: `Piece`, `Pawn`.

Comment: Thank you ! For some reason I got an error when I wrote the pawn about those variables so I re wrote them. Btw I changed the variables and class names, I need to get used to the conventions any info about them? again thank you

Comment: You should easily infer the conventions by looking at the javadoc of any of the thousands of classes of the JDK. But google is your friend: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: Thank you for your help I will take all to my attention

Comment: "Also, your code is unreadable to any Java developer" - if you can't read code just because it uses unusual naming conventions, then you can't be very good at thinking about code.